# How to change obscure character of text field in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to use '*' instead of '•' in text field.

```
TextField(
  focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
  controller: _passwordController,
  obscureText: true,
);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify, you want to show a character that is not the standard "ball" as the obscured character?

Answer (score 7):

Now flutter does support this feature for a textfield by setting the [obscuringCharacter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/obscuringCharacter.html) property, it takes a string strict to 1 character and the obscureText property should be true in order to take this effect

```
TextField(
  obscuringCharacter: '&', // defaults to *
  obscureText: true,
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Flutter currently does not support this feature. Obscuring text is controlled by the property **obscureText** which takes a boolean expression. As you can see in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableText/obscureText.html)

> When this is set to true, all the characters in the text field are replaced by U+2022 BULLET characters (•).

This issue on GitHub may be of help: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36377

Answer (score 3):

```
TextField(
    obscureText: true,
    obscuringCharacter:'*',
);
```